# Web API controller throwing "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'JObject' from content with media type 'application/json'."

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am getting below Error from my Web API controller POST request when passing JSON objects from Postman

> "message": "The request entity's media type 'application/json' is not
> supported for this resource.",
> "innererror": {
> "message": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'JObject' from content with media type
> 'application/json'.",
> "type": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
> "stacktrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
> content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
> formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
> formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"

Same controller works fine when using Model as parameter type in POST request.

Working Post Request (here User is Model) :

```
    public IHttpActionResult CreateNewMailUser([FromBody] User param)
    {
        // code
    }
```

NOT working Post Request :

```
    public IHttpActionResult CreateNewUser([FromBody] JObject param)
    {
        // code
    }
```

Even I tried, but this also didn't work.

```
    public IHttpActionResult CreateNewUser(JObject param)
    {
        // code
    }
```

Any suggestion what I am missing here. I made sure Content-type is application/json.

Comment: Please show your Postman request, Newtonsoft.Json package version and .Net version you're using. I have tried the above code and worked fine with webapi 2 and .Net Framework 4.7 and 4.5. Also I didn't have to implement media formatter.